# Modular function in the Little Picard Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

These are 3 questions which are more or less related.

The Little Picard Theorem states that if the image of an entire function $f$ omits more than 1 point, then it is necessarily a constant. The proof proceeds by contradiction in assuming that $f(z)$ omits 2 points (wlog $0$ and $1$).
Now I guess the observation is that since $$f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$$ and also $$\lambda: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$$ where $\lambda$ is the modular lambda function, we (basically) can construct a map $$g=\lambda^{-1} \circ f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}.$$ From there, it is plain that $h=e^{ig}$ is bounded and therefore constant, by Liouville.

1. Now obviously I left out the intricacies. For example do I have to constrain $\lambda$ on the fundamental region as only there $\lambda$ is bijective?
2. What is the problem in using the function $j$ instead? Afterall they are just related, right?
3. Now in essence the proof shows that a function that omits 2 points is a constant, but how does this imply that an entire function that omits any more than 1 point is a constant? What if $3,4,5,...$ points are missed? What if an entire closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is omitted?

Comment: Thought I would type and answer instead and accidently hit "enter".

Comment: Can you maybe quickly elaborate on why (3) is a special case of omitting 2 points? I don't quite see it.

Comment: "into" and "onto" are not the same thing. You made no assumption that $f$ maps onto $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$; $f$ could map to ANY subset of $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. Meaning that if $f$ misses any number of countable or uncountable points that is greater than or equal to two, then the proof is exactly the same. You assumed $f$ maps INTO, you constructed $\lambda$ to be onto and 1-to-1.

Comment: Oh, right... Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I always assumed that in the proof $f$ maps "onto" $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$. But indeed, it is not necessary. Say f omits the (closed) unitcircle centered at $1/2$, then $0$ and $1$ are missed and when applying $\lambda^{-1}$ you get that $g=\lambda^{-1} \circ f$ is entire and it maps into some subset of $\mathbb{H}$ which is sufficient to show boundedness of $e^{ig}$.

Comment: Maybe as some follow up question:

1) If $f$ is entire and misses exactly 1 point, does that point become a singularity for $f^{-1}$? For instance $e^z$ misses $0$ and $\log z$ has a singularity at $0$.

2) Typically analytic functions allow analytic continuations. Why is $\lambda$ not extendable to the entire complex domain?

Comment: By definition, if $f(z)\not=A$, then $f^{-1}$ cannot be defined at $A$ (this is the definition of inverse and has nothing to do with complex/analytic). An extension of Picard's theorem is that given any non-polynomial entire function, $f$, then $f$ must take on every complex value an infinite number of times. Hence, every entire function has an infinite number of "branch-cut" inverses (n "branch-cuts for polynomials).

Comment: I mean from the $q=e^{i\pi\tau}$ expansion $\lambda=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n q^n$ we see that if $\tau$ is rational of the form $2P/Q$ then the series diverges as you sum over infinitely $1$s when $n$ is a multiple of $Q$. So essentially $\lambda$ has poles at a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which I guess has something to do with the impossibility of extending $\lambda$, right? Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: Well, you can extend $\lambda$ all you want manually, but you won't find anything that agrees with your extension at precisely the points where their domains meet. Moreover, if their domains intersect, then the extension is unique and known as analytic extension. But if their domains dont meet you can pick anything you like. You could pick functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that map the upper half plane to the first quadrant and the lower half plane to the second quandrant. Then piece wise you would have a function $f$ that maps $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{H}-(0,i\infty)$.

Comment: It is probably not correct to think of $log(z)$ as having an essential singularity. $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity (because it is defined everywhere but the singularity). But $log(z)$ is simply undefinable at zero because it's inverse function never had an output of zero. Think of it this way. $e^{1/z}$ has a Laurent series centered at zero, but $log(z)$ has no Laurent series centered at zero and cannot even have one defined.

Comment: I'm still thinking about your previous paragraph^^, but about the last I was not assuming for the singularity to mean essential, any pole or branch point (as $\log z$ has) would do. Maybe I was using singularity in the wrong context here as there are only 3 singularities: removable, poles and essential singularities which are all definable by their laurent expansion, while functions can not be cast in a laurent expansion about their branch points (only when the branchpoint is removed/subtracted somehow).

Comment: Exactly, branch points arise from creating inverses of other functions. Picard's extended theorem says all non-polynomials have an infinite number of such inverses. In general, the undefined points of inverses are not the same as singularities.

Comment: 1) The infinite number of such inverses corresponding to functions $f^{-1}$ to each Riemann Sheet ? 2) While branch points do arise from creating inverses of other functions, they also miraculously can be thought of as a collection of an infinite sum of poles ;). For example $$f(z)=\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}a}{a-z} = \log(1-1/z)$$ has branchpoints at $0$ and $1$ and a cut in between.

Comment: An uncountable sum of poles (essential is countable). I like that example. Yes, I believe you are correct the inverses would be the different Riemann "sheets", different starting points would give a different sequence of inverses.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that $f$ maps into $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. This does not mean that $f$ maps onto $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. Indeed $f$ could be missing many many values, but at least two values are known and missing.

However, $\lambda$ is constructed to be 1-to-1, onto and most importantly, invertible. Any $\lambda$ with these properties would work in the proof of Picard's theorem.

The heart of Picard's theorem is the fact that $\lambda$ (and many other entire functions like it) exist. Because of the existence of these functions, we are able to constrain every entire function to posses these types of properties.